# How to highlight cell if date format is incorrect or blank?

Tags: mysql, excel

I have an excel sheet with over 5000+ records.

I am trying to set the date column into correct format (dd/mm/yy)

Instead of visually looking at data to spot errors such as:

- Blanks
- Date inputted like this: `27//01/20` < notice the double `//`
- Or something like this: `27/01/20..` < notice the full stops

Is there an easier way of finding errors in date column?

Here is a sample of my column A:

[image]

1st and 4th row should be marked in red, because it is not correct format.

Reason I want to achieve is this is because I am needing to import it into MySQL with correct column types. Not all to be varchar.

Comment: Why is the data so corrupted?

Comment: It's been manually inputted by somebody. My Job is to fix this -_- and move into MySQL so everything is feeding correctly and can be analysed smoothly

Comment: It *might* be simpler to import the junk data and fix it in MySQL. Is the data consistently 'dmy'?

Comment: At least all the dates are the same date, which makes things easier.

Comment: @Strawberry hmm.. maybe - how can I fix it? Regarding the 'dmy', result after import into MySQL shows as `2019-03-14 00:00:00` which is perfectly fine.

Comment: *I am trying to set the date column into correct format (dd/mm/yy)* If incorrect date like '27//01/20' is nevertheless stored then the column datatype is string/text, not datetime. So simply add a column with converting formula (`B1=DATEVALUE(A1)`) and set this column to DATE format, and all incorrect values will be converted into `#VALUE!` (and you even may filter rows by it).

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional formatting - choose rule type 'Use formula...', enter formula `=NOT(ISNUMBER($A10))` for appropriate range and get red cells.

[image]